# Edit image in img tag with userscript?

Tags: css, userscripts

Would it be possible to edit an `HTML attribute` such as a image inside a `img` tag and switch the image with another image with a userscript? I only know how to make a userstyle and not a userscript.

Here's what I've tried so far, but it hasn't worked.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Steam*
// @namespace   http://userscripts.org/user/erraticfox
// @description %description%
// @include     http://store.steampowered.com/
// @exclude     %exclude%
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==


document.getElementById('#logo_holder img').src = 'http://i.imgur.com/ytgtQME.png' !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the details in your above question are correct, the following should work as needed.

```
document.getElementById("logo_holder").src="http://i.imgur.com/ytgtQME.png";
```